# Programa en Python que realice la busqueda de el Nodo H desde el Nodo A, ¿Realiza bien la busqueda?

Tags: python, python-3.7, busqueda, nodos, teoría-de-grafos

Este es mi código que he trabajado hasta ahora, y este es el grafico, lo que necesito es saber si realiza bien la búsqueda.
Lo que realiza el programa es buscar entre todos los nodos desde el nodo a comenzando del nodo izquierdo hasta el ultimo en la derecha y encontrar H.
[image: Grafo del que haré la búsqueda]

Aquí esta mi código:

```
  from queue import Queue
import queue

adj_list = {
    "A":["B","D","C"],
    "B":["A","D","C","E"],
    "C":["A","D","H"],
    "D":["B","A","C","F","H"],
    "E":["B","F","G"],
    "F":["E","G","D","H"],
    "G":["F","E","H"],
    "H":["C","D","F","G"],
    

}

visited = {}
level = {} #distancia
parent = {}
bfs_traversal_output = []
queue = Queue()

for node in adj_list.keys():
    visited[node] = False
    parent[node] = None
    level[node] = -1 
print (visited)
print (level)
print (parent)

s = "A"
visited[s] = True
level[s] = 0
queue.put(s)

while not queue.empty():
    u = queue.get()
    bfs_traversal_output.append(u)

    for v in adj_list[u]:
        if not visited[v]:
            visited[v] = True
            parent[v] = u
            level[v] = level[u]+1
            queue.put(v)
print (bfs_traversal_output)
```

[image: Aquí la imagen de la consola:]

Comment: No he revisado el código pero de momento veo un error. El diccionario de ayacencias no representa el grafo de la figura. Por ejemplo, segun tu diccionario, B tiene C en su lista de adyacentes, pero el grafo no muestra una conexión B-C

Comment: Tampoco veo por ningún sitio la condición de que haya encontrado H (y entiendo que debería parar al encontrarlo). Por otro lado la salida que imprime no es correcta, pues entiendo que debería imprimir la ruta que ha encontrado para llegar desde A hasta H, pero en la salida se ve que H no es el último nodo visitado, y además se ve que pasa de C a E, cosa que no puede hacer según el grafo (y la matriz de adyacencias). A menos que no esté entendiendo yo lo que se supone que ha de imprimir el programa

Comment: Las ruta más corta son H-C-A y H-D-A. ¿Ese es el resultado esperado?